# Trying to run a zend framework phpunit test in CLI, but can't change the include_path in php.ini file

Tags: zend-framework, phpunit, php

In the command prompt I ran the command "php --ini" and its showing me that the file used is: C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\php.ini

I then tried to change the include path directive by uncommenting it and making it:
include_path = ".;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.8\pear;C:\Users\xxx\My Documents\Aptana Studio Workspace\xxx\library\Zend;"

However, this does not change the include path and I have no idea why not.

Comment: Is your bootstrap file for the phpunit tests setting the include path manually for some reason? It might be overriding the include path from the .ini file.

Comment: Nope, I checked that already :(

Comment: What happens when you run phpunit? I'm assuming that's what you're trying to run.

Comment: Hey Jerry, well phpunit ran fine, I just ran into issues with setting the include path so some dependencies weren't able to be located.  Have since figured out the issue, but thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the issue is.  I have PEAR installed, and I didn't realize that instead of editing the example include_path directive it actually adds its own entry to the very bottom of the INI file.